# JSON.parse: unexpected character Issue

Tags: php, jquery, json

I can't figure it out why I am getting error "JSON.parse: unexpected character" in Firefox console.. Looks like the problem is around jQuery.parseJSON(data)); in comment.js file.. If I remove both if statements in my php file works everything well, but this is not what I need..

Thanks!

comment.php

```
<?php

require_once ("../modules/comments.php");
require_once ("../includes/db_connect.php");

 if(isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == 'comment_insert' ) {

    $userId = (int)$_POST['userId'];
    //$comment = addslashes(str_replace("\n", "<br>", $_POST['comment']));

    $comment = strip_tags($_POST['comment']); // remove html tags
    $comment = ucfirst(strtolower($comment)); 
    //$comment = addslashes(str_replace("\n", "<br>"));

    $std = new stdClass();
    $std->commentId = 24;
    $std->userId = $userId;
    $std->comment = $comment;
    $std->userName = "John Stu";
    $std->profile_img = "https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/avatar_48-vfllY0UTT.png";

     if(class_exists('Comments') && class_exists('Subscribers')) {

        $commentInfo = Comments::insertComments($comment, $userId);

        if($commentInfo != null) {


        }

    }   
        echo json_encode($std); 



 } else {

   //header("Location: /");

 }

?>
```

comment.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#post-comment-btn').click(function(){
        comment_post_btn_click();

    });

});


function comment_post_btn_click(){

var _comment = $('#comment-post-text').val();
        var _userId = $('#userId').val();
        var _userName = $('#userName').val();

        if(_comment.length > 0 && _userId != null) {

        $.post("ajax/comment_insert.php", {
            task    : "comment_insert",
            userId  : _userId,
            comment : _comment,

        }).done(function(data) {

         comment_insert(jQuery.parseJSON(data));    
         console.log("ResponseText:" + data);

            });

            console.log(_comment + " Username: " + _userName + " User Id: " + _userId);

        } else {

            console.log("The text area is empty..");

        }

        $('#comment-post-text').val("");

}

function comment_insert(data) {


    var t = '';

    t += '<li class="comment-holder" id="_'+data.comment_id+'">';                       
    t += '<div class="user-img">';
    t += '<img src="'+data.profile_img+'">';
    t += '</div>';
    t += '<div class="comment-body">';
    t += '<h3 class="username-field">'+data.userName+'</h3>';
    t += '<div class="comment-text">'+data.commen+'</div>';
    t += '</div>';
    t += '<div class="comment-buttons-holder">';
    t += '<ul>';
    t += '<li class="delete-btn">X</li>';
    t += '</ul>';
    t += '</div>';
    t += '</li>';

    $('.comments-holder-ul').prepend(t);
}
```

Comment: can you show the output of console.log("ResponseText:" + data);  ?

Comment: @tan I am getting only: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Comment: google chrome > VM7285:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (comment.js:26)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: It means you have error in your `php` code.. use `try..catch` and `return exception` as json response.. then you'll be able to see what is php error.

Comment: if you place the line console.log("ResponseText:" + data); before comment_insert(jQuery.parseJSON(data));, then it might output what data is in "data".

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have some Error/Warning in your PHP file.
Try this,
`Inspect > Network >Select XHR` and make the AJAX call.
Now you'll see the PHP response in `Response` tab.
(Better use Google Chrome)

Because PHP Errors/Warnings are wrapped up with HTML tags which starts from `"<"`.
(Example `<div>Undefined Index</div>`)

Answer (score 0):

First clean the output buffer and then terminate the current script. try below code:

**comment.php**

```
require_once ("../modules/comments.php");
require_once ("../includes/db_connect.php");

 if(isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == 'comment_insert' ) {

    $userId = (int)$_POST['userId'];
    //$comment = addslashes(str_replace("\n", "<br>", $_POST['comment']));

    $comment = strip_tags($_POST['comment']); // remove html tags
    $comment = ucfirst(strtolower($comment)); 
    //$comment = addslashes(str_replace("\n", "<br>"));

    $std = new stdClass();
    $std->commentId = 24;
    $std->userId = $userId;
    $std->comment = $comment;
    $std->userName = "John Stu";
    $std->profile_img = "https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/avatar_48-vfllY0UTT.png";

     if(class_exists('Comments') && class_exists('Subscribers')) {

        $commentInfo = Comments::insertComments($comment, $userId);

        if($commentInfo != null) {


        }

    }   

    // Clean the output buffer
    ob_clean();

    echo json_encode($std); 

    // Terminate the current script
    die();

 } else {

   //header("Location: /");

 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning json data, you have to indicate it to the $.post function in adding the last parameter (otherwise, `data` won't be a json object)...

```
$.post("ajax/comment_insert.php", {
    task : "comment_insert",
    userId  : _userId,
    comment : _comment,
},,"json").done(...
```

Change that and check if the error persists...